# ERROR: operator does not exist: varchar >= integer when changing column type int to varchar in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, casting, liquibase

I have a task to create a Liquibase migration to change a value affext in table trp_order_sold, which is right now int8, to varchar (or any other text type if it's more likely to be possible).

The script I made is following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.trp_order_sold
    ALTER COLUMN affext SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR
    USING affext::varchar;
```

I expected that `USING affext::text;` part is gonna work as a converter, however with or without it I am getting this error:

```sql
ERROR: operator does not exist: varchar >= integer
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong? Also I am writing a PostgreSQL script but a working XML equivalent would be fine for me as well.

Comment: This column could be used in a generated column, a constraint or a trigger, for example. Can you share the DDL for this table? EDIT: A check constraint could do that. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DDh4I4DS)

Comment: 1) It should work with just `ALTER TABLE public.trp_order_sold ALTER COLUMN affext  TYPE VARCHAR;` 2) This `ERROR: operator does not exist: varchar >= integer ` looks like  it is coming from something else. Is there another operation in the migration that is touching the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These would most typically use or depend on your column:

- a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-generated-columns.html)
- a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)
- a trigger's `when` condition
- a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) or a [rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html)
- a [`check` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)

In my test ([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rsoV6gr9)) only the last one leads to the error you showed:

```sql
create table test_table(col1 int);
--CREATE TABLE
alter table test_table add constraint test_constraint check (col1 >= 1);
--ALTER TABLE
alter table test_table alter column col1 type text using col1::text;
--ERROR:  operator does not exist: text >= integer
--HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

You'll have to check the constraints on your table with `\d+` command in `psql`, or by [querying the system tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214877/242866):

```sql
SELECT con.*
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
               ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
               ON nsp.oid = connamespace
WHERE nsp.nspname = 'your_table_schema'
     AND rel.relname = 'your_table_name';
```

Then you will need to drop the constraint causing the problem and build a new one to work with your new data type.

---

Since integer 20 goes before integer 100, but text '20' goes after text '100', if you plan to keep the old ordering behaviour you'd need this type of cast:

```sql
case when affext<0 then '-' else '0' end||lpad(ltrim(affext::text,'-'),10,'0')
```

and then make sure new incoming `affext` values are cast accordingly in an insert and update trigger. Or use a [`numeric` ICU collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#id-1.6.11.4.5.7.5) similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/285230/242866).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The problem indeed was the constraint.